# Copy a string to char array

Tags: c++, string, char, type-conversion

I am trying to copy a string which might contain null characters in the middle to a char array.
I have constructed the following function.

```
 void SaveStringToChar(string &mystring,const char * &ArrChar)
 {//begin function

   std::string str;
   char * writable = new char[str.size() + 1];
   std::copy(str.begin(), str.end(), writable);
   writable[str.size()] = '\0';
   ArrChar = writable;

 }//end function
```

my question is this method guarantees that I wont lose the characters after a null element.
and my other question is I get this linker error which I don't know what it means.

> /tmp/ccUpCRaz.o: In function `Parser::RuleParser(char const*)':
>   Parser.cpp:(.text+0x3f6): undefined reference to           Parser::SaveStringToChar(std::basic_string,   std::allocator >&, char const*&)'
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

anyhint please.

this is the function I pass things to compare.

```
  void Search( size_t TextLength, const char *Text, const vector<const char *> &patterns );
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use [`std::string::c_str()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/) ?

Comment: I happen to used them but my string might contain null in the middle which I suspected that they are lost as I push them to a vector of type const char * because I rechecked the data in the vector after that and I found them lost

Comment: I'm not al all sure if the result of the c_str() function is guaranteed to contain all characters past the first `\0`. Even if you test it with one compiler, it may not behave in the same way on another.

Comment: I doubt they are really lost. However, since `c_str()` return a null-terminated string, you indeed have no way of telling if you really reached the end of the string when displaying it. Now an important question is: why would you want to deal with null-terminated strings if you know for sure they can contain null characters ? Sticking with `std::string` seems far less risky.

Comment: @MrLister: I don't have a copy of the standard at my disposal right now, but I'm fairly confident that it is guaranteed for `c_str()` to return all the characters of the string, null or not, in the resulting array. Could anyone confirm/infirm ?

Comment: What does the program do with the `char` array which you allocate? Chances are you could solve this issue (and a lot of others) by using `std::vector<char>` objects instead of raw `char` arrays. You can use objects of the former type in all cases where the latter is expected!

Comment: as I am not using it to printout I am using it for comparison purposes

Comment: Are you comparing to `const char*` from another source? Do they have embedded null characters? If so, how you know their true length?

Comment: well I read a line from a file then pass it to the comparison function using .c_str() with text.length() but it doesn't work for the patterns which contain null only for text that has letters (full words like DOG CAT but not DO-Null-G)

Comment: @user1231229, updated answer with alternative suggestion.

Comment: @ereOn I just found that `c_str()` _is_ guaranteed to contain all the characters in the `std::string`. So no problem there!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the function as a member of `Parser::`. It is currently defined as:

```
void SaveStringToChar(string &mystring,const char * &ArrChar)
```

Change to:

```
void Parser::SaveStringToChar(string &mystring,const char * &ArrChar)
```

The `std::copy()` will copy all the characters. However, the caller will not know how many characters `ArrChar` actually points to as functions like `strlen()` will stop counting at the first null character. You could change the signature of `SaveStringToChar()` to accept another argument `size_t& ArrCharLen` that would be populated with the number of characters in `ArrChar`. Of course, `mystring` will have the length of `ArrChar` so maybe you are already storing this prior to the call to `SaveStringToChar()`.

EDIT (after `vector<const char*>` comment):

The true number of bytes is lost once the `const char*` is added to the `vector`. Why not use a `vector<std::string>` and you have `std::string::length()` to know how many characters there are actually stored in `std::string`.

EDIT2 (after comparison function .c_str() with text.length():

Instead of passing `.c_str()` and `.length()` to compare against elements in a `vector<const char*>` just pass the `std::string` to the compare function and compare against elements of a `vector<std::string>`: the `std::string::operator==()` will correctly compare strings will embedded null characters. You could then use `std::find()` to search the `vector<std::string>` for the `std::string` read from the file.

Comment: will you have a point but this is not just simple comparison the search function is actually an algorithm that is built on those parameters so I can't just change my parameters like that (and to tell you the truth I tried to change it to string but it gave me a heap of errors that I couldn't fix).

Comment: What do you use to compare the `Text` and `TextLength` to entries in the `vector`? You need to store the length of the elements of the `vector` somewhere: changing to `vector<std::string>` seems the simplest approach.

Comment: You can still access each individual character using `std::string[]` if required.

Answer (score 1):

Your string copy seem fine, but if you are doing it to pass a char* to a function there are better ways see:

```
std::string str;
//...
my_func(str.c_str());
```

hmjd has your link error.

Answer (score 0):

See hmjd's answer for the link error.

As to the copied characters, you won't actually *lose* any characters, because they're all safely copied to the output buffer. However, if there are really `\0` characters in the middle of the string, none of the C-style string functions (like printf) will work correctly on it.
And also the calling routine won't know what the length of the string was, and therefore what the newly allocated size of the buffer is. You should return the string length too (either as the return value, or in another reference argument).

Comment: ok but as an array they will be there if I traverse it like A A null B C null null

Comment: as I am not using it to printout I am using it for comparison purposes

Comment: If you know what the exact length is, OK. Otherwise, C-style comparison functions won't function right either. By the way, it's possible to do comparison between `std::string`s; no need to copy them into character arrays first.

Answer (score 0):

> my question is this method guarantees that I wont lose the characters after a null element

The whole string will be copied into the buffer, even if it does contain null characters. `std::copy` does not interpret the data it copies in any way, it just copies the number of elements you tell it to.

However, if the string does contain null characters, then you *can't* use it with any function that works with null-terminated strings (such as those in `<cstring>`); they will interpret the first null character as the end of the string.

Also, at least in the code you posted, you are returning the pointer as `const char *`, implying that you won't be modifying the copy. In that case, do you actually need a copy of the string's data, or is it enough to return `str.c_str()` instead?

> my other question is I get this linker error

It looks like you're missing the definition of `Parser::SaveStringToChar`. I'm guessing that the code you've posted is from a source file, and not a function defined inline inside the `Parser` class. If that's the case, then you've forgotten to specify that it's a member function, and defined a non-member instead; change it to

```
void Parser::SaveStringToChar(string &mystring,const char * &ArrChar)
     ^^^^^^^^
```